# PHP 5.4.12 still problems with upload >2GB?

Tags: php, upload, debian

I have read somewhere that after PHP 5.4.4 the problem has been fixed for upload files >2GB (but did not see it in changelog). But I am still unable to upload via Chrome 3GB file.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem?

Debian 6, nginx 1.2.7.

Comment: Why on earth someone would upload a 3TB file with a web browser? In my opinion you should find a better solution for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614147/uploading-a-file-larger-than-2gb-using-php

Comment: You might want to reconsider uploading this file in one go. You could have a look at plupload to utilize chunked uploads

Comment: 3TB? Even if we assume you had the storage space neccessary (unlikely IMO), How long would it upload? Even if we assume a good line (24 Mbps - which is a typical _download_, not _upload_ speed where I live), it would still take [11.5 days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3TB%2F24Mbps) to upload.

Comment: Do you really mean 3 TB or rather 3 GB?

Comment: ... not to mention - you need to keep both parties _and_ the connection alive for the entire time. This alone is a challenging task.

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich good note (it still takes 17 minutes over said line).

Comment: damn im stupid, 3GB ofc, sry, gonna edit

Comment: this is a rediculous idea, do not upload files that big via HTTP :)

Comment: 3GB file via http is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, some info after quickly checking around. In the documentation to post_max_size (which is apparently not in effect after PHP 4.2.3, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) it is told that memory_limit is also relevant for file uploads. If I get it right this means that PHP will store the full file in memory during the upload. This tells me that some chunking would be smart... If you don't have a lot of RAM available that is. If you have that much RAM available it seems you have to increase the memory_limit, too.
Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: hmm I've got 8GB ram and memory_limit is set to 1024M and uploading 2GB file without chunking is not a problem. It can't reserve whole memory limit, cause several concurrent uploads would burn the server.

Comment: Sorry, then I'm at a loss.

Comment: nginx client body size, upload file size limit, post size limit, everything is set fine. Following the bug http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=685383 it seems like just a part of php5.4+ is fixed, not all the parts...