# Uploading very large images with PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, large-files

I am trying to develop a PHP site in which the user will be able to upload images to a server. I am pretty sure PHP has a max upload size of 10 MB. Problem is, some of the images may be as large as 2-4 GB. What do you think my best option is for doing this? FTP? I am looking for the easiest solution possible. Thank you.

Comment: Well, ftp would support interrupted transfers... which may be very likely with files of that size. PHP Max upload size is adjustable to whatever you like though.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be not to use a direct PHP process in this in any way (preferably). Note however that the max_upload_size can be changed, it's juat a safety precaution.

[uploading-a-file-larger-than-2gb-using-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614147/uploading-a-file-larger-than-2gb-using-php) should help you get this answered better though

Answer (score 0):

Just Create .htaccess file in your project root.

and paste this code.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 4G

php_value post_max_size 4G

php_value max_execution_time 2000

php_value max_input_time 2000
```

Hope it will work for you.

Thanks.